# How to set event handlers in a compact form in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, event-handling, symfony4, event-driven, event-dispatching

I'm writing a Symfony 4 application. Its core is a process with some nested sub-processes. In general, the idea, how to handle it looks like this:

There are some `process`es (hierarchy of the main processes and its sub-processes). Every process has a set of `state`s. Every process has a set of allowed `event`s.

The facade of this mechanism is the `SystemEventHander`. It registers the handled processes, analyses the incoming requests, and find and execute the appropriate handler for the current event.

**`services.yaml`**

```
# events
App\Process\SystemEventHandlerInterface:
    class: 'App\Process\SystemEventHandler'
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: general:user_message_received, method: handle }
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: process_a:foo, method: handle }
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: process_a.process_b:foo, method: handle }
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: process_a.process_c:bar, method: handle }
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: process_a.process_d:baz, method: handle }
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: process_a.process_d.process_e:buz, method: handle }
```

So my all custom events are initially handled by only one handler: the `SystemEventHandler()`.

The proble is, that for every single event I have to write nearly the same line:

```
- { name: kernel.event_listener, event: process_name:event_name, method: handle }
```

Only `process_name:event_name` varies, the rest is static.

Image I have a big number of events -- 30? 50? 100? How can I avoid explicitly writing a new line for every single one?

Comment: [Event Subscribers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-subscriber) are what you are looking for.  Of course if you really do end up with 100 different event types all handled by the same listener then I suspect you may have a design flaw.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks for your comment! I know, what you mean with "design flaw", but I think, it's not the case here. The reason is, that I actually have multiple `Process`es, every process can have `State`s and the handlers actually look like `App\ProcessHandling\ProcessFoo/StateBar#onEventBuz(...)`. The `App\Process\SystemEventHandler\handle(...)` is just the entry point / a facade.